# Manipulate day-of-week number

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-datetime

I have data with dates, but I want to do more in terms of time. I created a function that would manipulate week to start whenever I chose, ie 0 would be Wednesday instead of Sunday. it also adds in the monthly label to my dataframe:

```
def date_manipulate(df,startday):
    df['Month']=df.index.strftime("%B")
    df['DOW']=df.index.strftime("%A")
    week = {}
    default_week =['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday']
    temp_week = default_week[startday:] + default_week[0:startday]
    for index, day in enumerate(temp_week):
        week[day] = index
    df.replace({"DOW":week},inplace=True)
    return df
```

Then I aggregated them using groupby for year and week.

```
def data_agg(df,name):
    df_monthly=df.groupby([(df['name']),(df.index.year),(df['Month']),(df.index.week),(df['DOW']),(df.index)],sort=True)
    df_monthly=cal_columns(df_monthly)
    df_monthly.index.names=['Name','Year','Month','Week','Day of Week','date']
    df_monthly.to_csv('data/{}_Aggregate.csv'.format(name))
```

And this is fine except the week doesn't take consideration that Wednesday to Tuesday is now the 7 day week instead of Sunday to Saturday. My thought to solve this would do a loop of 7 days starting from 0 to 6. But this creates a different issue, if the data don't go through the full week, ie only have Wednesday, Thursday,Friday, and the following Wednesday data is missing then there is no clear identifier on when this week ends or when next week starts. I feel I'm in a logic sink right now. Really need some light into this, thanks.

So an example of what I'm trying to get at is similar to this

```
Week  day of the week  randdata
1         Wednesday       1
1         Thursday        3
1         Friday          4 
2         Wednesday       1 
2         Saturday        5
2         Sunday          6
3         Thursday        6
3         Friday          7
```

As I'm editing, I just had a spark.

Start from Wednesday, start counting consecutive days base on the dates, then if there is a gap between the date, start a new week otherwise the next Wednesday is the start of the new week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments above, I'm more concerned with applying the correct week number to the data. I was able to resolve it using the following code. The logic is as follows. 
1) First convert date index to ordinal 
2) use the ordinal number to calculate out start and end date of week knowing 7 day is always fixed.
3) Assign the week number to the data

```
offset=list(week.values())[df['DOW'][0]]
startdate=df['temp_date'][0]-(offset)
enddate=startdate+6
week=1
df['week']=0
for counter, day in enumerate (df['temp_date']):
    #if df.loc[counter, 'merchant_name']==current_merchant:
    if df['merchant_name'][counter]==current_merchant:
        if(df['temp_date'][counter])<=enddate:
            df['week'][counter]=week
        else:
            enddate+=7
            week+=1
            df['week'][counter]=week
    else:
        current_merchant=df['merchant_name'][counter]
        startdate=df['temp_date'][counter]-(offset)
        enddate=startdate+6
        week=1
        df['week'][counter]=week
```

Answer (score 0):

> I created a function that would manipulate the week to start whenever I choose, ie 0 would be Wednesday instead of Sunday.

You can do this a bit more efficiently with `DatetimeIndex.dayofweek` (or `Series.dt.dayofweek`), applying an offset before calling this property:

> The day of the week with Monday=0, Sunday=6

```
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> days = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday',
            'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']

>>> def custom_dayofweek(ser, startday='Monday'):
       # Use enumerate/reversed dict if you really want
       #     to optimize speed
       offset = days.index(startday)
       if isinstance(ser, pd.Series):
           # otherwise: assume DatetimeIndex
           ser = ser.dt
       return (ser - offset).dayofweek

>>> rng = pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=72)

>>> custom_dayofweek(rng, startday='Sunday')
Int64Index([6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1,
            ...
            5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0],
           dtype='int64', length=72)
```

You can test that things correctly line up:

```
>>> rng.weekday_name
Index(['Saturday', 'Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday',
       'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday', 'Monday',
       ...
       'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday',
       'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'],
      dtype='object', length=72)

>>> custom_dayofweek(rng, 'Wednesday')
Int64Index([3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,
            ...
            2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
           dtype='int64', length=72)
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for optimizing my code. I am more concerned with the second section.  How do I aggregate week properly instead of default sunday to Saturday scenario? If my week starts on a Wednesday, how do I change the week to run from Wednesday to Tuesday instead of Sunday to Saturday. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, not sure if I'm following you @Longroadahead just based on your code.  It would help if you could add some example input/output data that represents where you're trying to get to.

Comment: I just edited the question, I also lay out my thought process as I'm editing. I'm going to try to solve this on my own in the mean time. Thanks again.